What are the steps to use newly created agents in salesforce application?
We have created two service agents to test Agentforce's capabilities. Topics and actions have been configured based on the requirements. While testing in conversation preview mode, we are able to get the expected answers. However, when testing with the actual Einstein Copilot, the same set of questions does not work.
Are we missing any steps, or does making an agent usable in the application involve a different set of procedures?
Thanks,
Puneet Tyagi
